# Charging series batteries off USB

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I'm designing a project that requires battery power and a ~6V supply. Accordingly, I'm planning to use two 3.7V batteries lithium ion in series (probably [these](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/dtp-103048-li-ion-3-7v_62437812323.html?spm=a2700.wholesale.0.0.5c024bc0oWtN96)). I need to charge these batteries off a 5V USB supply while in-project (they are going to be attached to a custom PCB with headers).

All of the battery charger ICs I've found on digikey or similar all require a higher voltage than the maximum series voltage of the battery, even if they support "multiple cells". I'd like to avoid a boost converter on the output (i.e. charging in parallel is undesirable), so have come up with two options:

1. Use a boost converter on the charging side, then connect the increased voltage to a charger IC. Will this cover me with respect to balance charging?
2. Use multiple single-cell charger ICs, give each 5V from the USB port, and charge each cell "individually". This means one of my chargers will have Vss at a potential other than circuit ground. This might work if the charger has an isolated output, but feels dangerous.

Is there a better third option? This has to be a solved problem, right?

Comment: what is this question asking? ... `This has to be a solved problem, right?`

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this. I'm assuming there's an easy way I've missed since this is a common enough issue

Comment: Maybe search some manufacturer websites? E.g. https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ics/products.html#p1152=2;2&p273=Switch-Mode%20Boost

Comment: It might be simpler to use a single cell with existing USB charging solutions and a step-up regulator for the *load*. Otherwise you need a step-up anyway for charging 2 cells from a 5V USB source.

Comment: usb=5V. so charges 3.7V.  to avoid boost, need have load use ~3V-3.3V and regulate 5V and 3.7V down to load.  If you need more, best bet might be to boost the 5V during charging.

Comment: Boosting on output is non-ideal due to current requirements. Boosting during charging is an option but I would still need to balance charge the two cells, right?

Comment: I also have no microcontroller in this project (going for a "dumb" design"), and it seems that 2S balance chargers without I2C don't exist.